# Find out whether a library supports c++ 11

Tags: c++11

I am using a 3rd party C++ library. i don't know whether it is using C++ 11 or not? Is there some trivial check by running code based on the library to find whether it is based on C++ 11 or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile it with a C++11 compiler.